# How to keep SharePoint dev machines fast and responsive?

Tags: performance, sharepoint

I've been working on SharePoint platforms for two years and have used variety of machines for my SharePoint development. When I create a new box, initially the box will be fast and the web applications will be responsive. But later the machines get very slow and unresponsive during development. And I'm using any virtual machines.

I don't install any heavy application apart from SQL Server 2008, VS 2010 and SP 2010, MS Office 2010 which are mandatory.

What are the tricks to keep the machines faster? Any configuration tweaks with the SharePoint server or the machine, any best practices etc.?

My Spec -

HP Pavilion DV4 with i5 2.27GHz, 4GB RAM DDR2, 320GB disk, 64 bit Windows Server 2008 R2, SharePoint 2007 (or) SharePoint 2010, VS 2010 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 2):

My main recommendation is to get SQL on a separate, shared, box or pop an SSD drive in your system.

If you are wondering why it is being slow then have a look at your windows performance counters.

I assume your SharePoint box has direct internet connectivity. If not then have a look at [this post](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/04/new-approach-to-solve-sharepoints.html).

[Idera recently posted](http://www.idera.com/Downloads/ProdCollateral/Tune-Your-DB-Conf-Best-SP-Perf.pdf) some info about tuning your database for SQL Usage as well.

Comment: SSD drive might not help. I believe the likely problem is that SQL is a memory hog...

Comment: Depends on how things are set up. An investigation in perf counters will show the source of the problem.

Comment: Yes.... but SQL is a memory hog :-) Seriously though, SQL Server assumes that it is the only important process that would run on the machine and actually commits a lot of memory on startup. There might be a config setting to change that, though, but I am not sure if sharepoint messes with it. But of course you are right, we have to look before we conclude.

Comment: There is a well known config setting to change that - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067.aspx

Comment: Actually SSD drive might help even if the cause is that SQL is a memory hog. It will help make paging faster (which will happen frequently). Anyway...

Comment: Can you brief more on how to check the 'perf counters'?

Comment: Have a look at this Google search regarding Perfcounters and SQL - http://www.google.co.uk/webhp?q=using+sql+server+performance+counters&btnG=Google+Search